# Does Swift have CPU caching like Java does?

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

In Java, CPU cores can cache variables in their registers, meaning that in a multi-threaded application, each core might see a different value for the same variable, which can be a source of bugs. To prevent this behaviour, you can mark the variable `volatile` e.g:

```
private volatile int x;
```

Does swift also have this CPU caching behaviour, and if so, is there an equivalent keyword to Java's `volatile` to prevent it?

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966354/lock-free-shared-variable-in-swift-functioning-volatile

Comment: `var x = 10` is already atomic